# How to remove item from list item?

Tags: android, listview

```
private void listData() {

    SimpleCursorAdapter list = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.wordsee_row,
            cursor,
            new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_LANG,DBAdapter.KEY_WORD_TH, DBAdapter.KEY_WORD, DBAdapter.KEY_WORD_READING},
            new int[] {R.id.lang, R.id.th_word, R.id.word, R.id.reading});
    setListAdapter(list);
    db.close();
}
```

from above each list contain 4 items (id.lang, id.th_word, id.word, id.reading)

and I want to remove it by use primary key (KEY_WORD_SEE_ID ) like this

```
case DELETE_ID:{
            db.open();
            db.deleteRecord(DBAdapter.WORDS_SEE_TABLE,DBAdapter.KEY_WORD_SEE_ID,cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdapter.KEY_WORD_SEE_ID)));
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.save_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            setBinding();
            listData();

            return true;
        }
```

and this is my delete function

```
public boolean deleteRecord(String tableName, String indicatorName,
        long rowId) {
    return db.delete(tableName, indicatorName + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work and no force close

what should I do?

Comment: any error? you could also try to log using `log.d`

Answer (score 0):

use requery on your cursor..
like this cursor.requery();(After deleting item from DB)
this will update list with item deleted...
if this doesnot work then post with full description..

Comment: no it show list again after press delete but the list that I deleted show again too.

Comment: Check boolean return of your deleteRecord function.. if it is false then there is something error. debug it.. print in Logcat